# Multi step php form

Tags: php, forms, html-email

I am using a 3 step php form that sends data to my email. I use three different php file for that.

First form should store data as `$_SESSION` and redirect to the next form. Second form does the same. But when I complete the third (last) form it only sends the data from the third form. Does't get the stored data from the first two form.

As I have `php 5.3+ version`, I can't use `session_register();`. Here is all the forms scripts.

Here are [Form 1 and Form 2](http://pastebin.com/FNbY1MNE)

And [Form 3](http://pastebin.com/BqLJzNpa)

I don't know what I missed. Is there any other way to store and use input data? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An approach I've used is to store all the data from the previous step in hidden inputs (`<input type="hidden">`) with the same name. That way they're all accessible in `$_POST[]`.

**Note:** If you do this, have any password fields on the last step. You should not be putting passwords in your HTML in plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the problem with your code is that you put the `redirection` header before the session var was set.

I mean, this part:

```
$_SESSION['condition_home'] = $_POST['condition_home'];
$_SESSION['selling_plan'] = $_POST['selling_plan'];
$_SESSION['comment'] = $_POST['comment'];
```

should be before `header('Location: second_page.php');`

Comment: Yes, that's maybe the problem. But how can I solve it? Any suggestion?

Comment: Put the `$_SESSION`s part right before the `header`

Comment: Actually I can't. Form1 has one session, then it redirects to the second form. Second form has three Sesssions, then it redirects to the third form. And third form collects all the stored Sessions from form1, form2. That's how it should work. I think I need to find some way to store $_SESSION before redirection. Any further suggestion?

Comment: Did you mean `$_SESSION` or session ? From your codes, I can see that you only have one session but many session variables. Session variables are shared between all the pages that use the session.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is one session and 4/5 session variables. The variable are lost when I call them in the last form. I know it happens because of the redirection but I can't find a way to solve it.

Comment: No error. It sends variables from only the last form ($name, $email_address, $phone) and left the first two as blank. Just lost the $_SESSION variables.

Comment: I'm really lost here. I've tried your codes on my server. But got no problem. Worked as intended.

Comment: If you cannot use session than you have to use the hidden field solution like the answer above

Comment: Okay, I just tried it with another server (php 5.2..) and works fine. So there's some problem with the previous server (php 5.3.3) itself I think. Thanks anyway.